# add numbers to new lines separated by comma

Tags: php

i am having some issues with my php code. what i wish to add numbers like before every lines something like below

```
1. some data
2. some more data
```

what i have tried doing is like below but it would not multiply the numbers like i want it to, it only prints 1

```
$num = 1;
$tdetails = $num++. str_replace(',', '<br />', $row['travellers_details']);
```

Could someone please show how to achieve what i am looking for?

thanks

Comment: _"it only prints 1"_ - What do you expect? You only echo the variable `$num` once? This question is very unclear.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in front of every line i wish to add numbers how can i do it? please

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. It's unclear what your code is, what your input is, what your output is and what it should be. Please extract a [mcve] to clarify the code part.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry for my bad english, i just do not understand how to explain it. i tried to give example also in the begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate and increment `num` each time. You can store the elements in an array first using `explode`:

```
$num = 1;
$tdetails = explode(',', 'some data, some more data'); 
$str = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($tdetails); $i++)
     $str .= $num++ . ". ". $tdetails[$i] . "<br>";
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
1. some data
2. some more data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of HTML `ol`(ordered list) tag which will automatically do the numbering for you.

```
<?php

$tdetails = "<ol><li>" . implode("</li><li>", explode(",",$row['travellers_details'])) . "</li></ol>";

echo $tdetails;
```